# tweenmax animation runs without waiting for scrollmagic trigger

Tags: javascript, gsap, scrollmagic

I know the question have been asked multiple times but i checked all the solutions and my problem remains. I also used the indicator and the page had not reached the trigger. the tween max animation runs without the page reaching the trigger. the only difference my page has with the examples is that my scene is a fixed box on bottom of the page and i use the "affix" class of bootstrap for it. and i'm animating bunch of svgs.
here's the working demo with problem.
http://baharantadbir.com/About-Kish.html

Comment: Your question will stand a better chance of being answered if you clarify what the problem is (ideally a MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and clean up the formatting.

Comment: thanks. i gonna put a working demo